# Comparing revisions in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Coming from Subversion I have used the "Mark For Comparison" and "Compare URLs" feature in TortoiseSVN. This gave me the ability to compare the development branch with the last release version to get a list of files that changed.

We use this list of files for final code review, documentation of the next version, etc.

As you can see it is possible to get a list of files and also be able to click each file to see a visual diff of the changes.

[image: Screenshot of comparing revisions with Subversion]

Is it possible to do something similar with Mercurial? The best I have found thus far is this command, however the list of files is far less useful than what I was able to get with Subversion.

`hg status --change  {revisionnumber}`

Comment: Yes. As far as I can tell the "Mark For Comparison" and "Compare URLs" feature does not exist in TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the command-line you can:

- `hg diff -r <first changeset> -r <second changeset>` or
- `thg vdiff -r <first changeset> -r <second changeset>`

In TortoiseHg, you can also select the 2 revisions you want to compare and get a visual diff as shown below:

[image]